# AWS CloudFormation Secret Manager dynamic reference won't return the value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I have a very stupid situation.
This is my very simple CF template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
   MyIAMUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:fedtest:SecretString:login}}'
      LoginProfile:
        Password: 'password'
```

secret "fedtest" exists, permissions OK. The template and the secret are in the same region.
But CF creates a user with name "{{resolve:secretsmanager:fedtest:SecretString:login}}" instead of the secret login value.
I used resolve:secretsmanager many times and it always works fine.

Maybe I have a heatstroke... this is only possible reason :))))
Have no idea what is wrong :(

Comment: Its not supported in that case. AWS documnetation that claims that `dynamic reference can be used in all resource properties`  is wrong. You have to get used to outdated/wrong/incomplete info in aws docs if you want to work with AWS.

Comment: @Marcin, thanks for your advice. 
My main problem that the same issue I experienced with Beanstalk when I try to pass secret value to env variables
`aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    USER: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:Fed-Tutorial-Beanstalk:SecretString:USER}}'
    PASSWD: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:Fed-Tutorial-Beanstalk:SecretString:PASSWD}}'`
I did everything as it written in the docs <https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.remote-repo> and have the same result - text instead of value